# Understanding ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider

Tags: ios, swift, sign-in-with-apple

Working with sign in with Apple and in their sample code they have:

```
let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(),
                ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]
```

And I am confused understanding the difference between them, and also the impact on trying to use both of them.

Am I right in saying that `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider.createRequest()` is a request for using Sign in with Apple and `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()` is a request for using a username and password that may already be stored to the keychain?

Then, if I create an `ASAuthorizationController` with the previous requests as follows:

```
let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
```

if one fails, is it correct to say that they both fail?

So for this scenario, if my app does not have any previous credentials saved with the keychain, and I make those two requests the second one will fail because I don't have anything saved? I'm pretty confused as to why to use the two requests.

Comment: Have you come up with any results on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not @ZoltanVinkler. My use case evolved into not needing to check the keychain for previously saved credentials, so I dropped the `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` request. I would still like to know the answer to this!

Comment: Would love to know as well as I have the same issue with ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider not working...

Comment: +1 here, all the sample code retrieves that said username/password using `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider()` but doesn't show how to save it there.

So i guess it's to transition from some old, legacy ways?
not clear how they intended this to work with net-new apps

Comment: `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` is replacement for `SecRequestSharedWebCredentials`, which was deprecated in iOS 14. For some reason its counterpart, `SecAddSharedWebCredential`, was left as is. Unsurprisingly, there's no documentation, but AFAICT `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider` allows the user to pick from any shared web credentials belonging to the domain specified in your site's AASA file. That is to say it does almost the same thing as calling `SecRequestSharedWebCredentials(nil, nil, { _, _ in ... })`.

Answer (score -1):

i did a few trials and errors, found some clue. Still not sure when does the `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`  actually work, but i would separate these two requests, using `ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider`  first, then when it fails/succeeds, i call the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider`  request.

```
func perfomExistingAccountSetupFlows() {
    
    let passwordProvider = ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider()
    let passwordRequest = passwordProvider.createRequest()
    
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController.init(authorizationRequests: [passwordRequest])
    
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    
    authorizationController.performRequests()
  }
```

then in delegate:

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    
    var errorStr : String?
    print(errorStr ?? "something wrong with apple auth")
    print((error as NSError).code)
    print(ASAuthorizationError.canceled.rawValue,ASAuthorizationError.failed.rawValue,ASAuthorizationError.invalidResponse.rawValue,ASAuthorizationError.notHandled.rawValue,ASAuthorizationError.unknown.rawValue)
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    print((error as NSError).userInfo)
    
    guard let mes = (error as NSError).userInfo["NSLocalizedFailureReason"] else {return}
    print(mes as! String)
    print(mes as! String == "No credentials available for login.")
    if(mes as! String == "No credentials available for login."){
      AppleAuth.shared.init_auth()
    }
    
  }
```

even if it worked, i would still resolve back to `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider` simply because it's better documented than the other.

```
  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    var user:String,
        email:String,
        nickname:String,
        identityToken:String,
        authorizationCode:String;
    
    if authorization.credential.isKind(of: ASPasswordCredential.classForCoder()) {
      
      // Sign in using an existing iCloud Keychain credential.
      let passworCreddential = authorization.credential as! ASPasswordCredential
      
      user = passworCreddential.user
      
      let password = passworCreddential.password
      print("---",passworCreddential.description,password,passworCreddential)
      
      AppleAuth.shared.init_auth()
    }
  }
  

  func init_auth() {
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController.init(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
  }
```

it seems to work better than directly calling the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider`  , which sometimes fails...

will update if anything goes wrong from here....

Comment: This is by far the most unreadable code I have ever seen

Comment: how would you like them to be improved?

Comment: Format it in Xcode

Comment: they have been, seen from my side.